# How to return to the previous point in Vim

Tags: vim

In Vim there is a command ``.` to return exactly to where last edited text.

But my question is: How to make it automatic? What I mean is, every time I exit and reopen the same file again, it brings me to the point where I left.

I saw my friend's Vim has that behavior but he doesn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 11):

I use these commands a lot:

<kbd>CTRL-O</kbd> Go to [count] Older cursor position in jump list
            (not a motion command).

<kbd>CTRL-I</kbd> Go to [count] newer cursor position in jump list
            (not a motion command).

<kbd>ma</kbd> Set mark `a` at cursor position (does not move
            the cursor, this is not a motion command).

<kbd>'a</kbd> Jump to the mark `a` in the current buffer.

<kbd>gi</kbd> Insert text in the same position as where Insert mode
            was stopped last time in the current buffer.

Answer (score 10):

You'll want to read [this vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session).

Comment: +1: While @kev's answer is useful, this is exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 4):

Read this: `:help last-position-jump`

Answer (score 2):

Put this lines on your ~/.vimrc file

```
 " When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
 autocmd BufReadPost *
 \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
 \   exe "normal g`\"" |
 \ endif
```

This only will help you next time you open vim to restore your cursor position.

Another idea is placing this on your ~/.bashrc

```
lvim='vim -c "normal '\''0"'
```

It will allow you to open the last edited file.

### Update!

```
alias lvim="vim -c':e#<1'"
```

The above alias will open vim in command mode `-c` to edit an alternative file `#` in this case the first one `<1` which is the last one.

For neovim I have this:

In your `init.lua`

```
  require('autocmds')
```

In your lua directory create a file called `autocmds.lua`:

```
local augroups = {}

augroups.restore_position {

restore_cursor_position = {
    event = "BufRead",
    pattern = "*",
    command = [[call setpos(".", getpos("'\""))]],
},

}

for group, commands in pairs(augroups) do
local augroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("AU_"..group, {clear = true})

for _, opts in pairs(commands) do
    local event = opts.event
    opts.event = nil
    opts.group = augroup
    vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(event, opts)
end
end
```